# installing programs

Tags: delphi, installation

This might be a very stupid question, but I still dont completely understand and had some hope thats someone here could fill in the blanks for me.

I have been playing around with programming for sometime now. And created some simple programs. nothing special nothing big. but when you download something from the internet you normally get an instalation file which installs the program you download. What I don't understand that is for. I have created a small application with delphi, which does save files, not very big ones. These are types of files that the user is not going to go looking for in a folder, you don't save it in a location. I was wondering how I could create a program that makes a folder in lets say program files and always saves the things there. Loading from there as well. The application.exe will be there as well and when you install it, it places a shortcut to the application.

is this possible with delphi?

Comment: The InnoSetup mentioned by David is written in Delph and Open Source, so *yes, this is possible in Delphi.*

Comment: *Anything* is possible in Delphi (and every other mainstream language as well).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would certainly be possible write your own installation program with Delphi, but it would be very unusual to do so.

Standard practice is to use a 3rd party tool to generate an installation program. Most modern Windows programs come in the form of an .msi which is a Windows Installer database.

There are many tools for creating installation programs:

- InstallShield
- InstallAware
- NSIS
- WiX
- Wise
- InnoSetup
- etc.

You also talk about writing and reading program configuration files. You need to be careful about where these are placed. You should not put them under the Program Files directory because modern versions of Windows do not permit users to write to those folders. This is why you are used to seeing UAC dialogs when you install software – they need to gain elevated rights in order to install.

Instead you should save program configuration files in one of the assortment of possible locations designed for just this situation, for example, the [`CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494%28VS.85%29.aspx) folder.

Comment: I would recommend InnoSetup.

Comment: +2 for listing InnoSetup and -1 for not putting it at the top of the list!

Comment: @Andreas I have no personal preference. I let me staff organise the installation program for my software! I believe that we use WiX.

Comment: Do we have a rule not to put subjective comments? hahaha, I would recommend Inno Setup!!!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, what would you recommend if I have license for WISE? Use Wise or InnoSetup? What about Visual Studio installation project?

Comment: @ALZ Impossible to say. The big question is whether or not you need to make a .msi. If so then Inno and NSIS are out, IIRC. Personally we use WiX. Not sure I'd recommend that to anyone other than a hard core pro.

Comment: Yes, I need *.MSI, but what do You mean "a hard core pro"?

Comment: Well forget NSIS and Inno. And VS install product no longer exists. WiX involves knowing .msi at low level and writing XML. Think there are GUIS for it but I cannot see the point. Basically .msi is hard.